# Matching trouble in UIMA RUTA?

Tags: nlp, uima, ruta

I have a lot of text like this:

(((((WORD1 Some text tokenA)))))

(((((WORD2 Some text tokenA)))))

(((((WORD3 Some text tokenB)))))

and etc.

I need match only "WORD№" blocks. I try some code like this:

```
ANY[5,5]{REGEXP("(") -> MARK(Begin)};

ANY[5,5]{REGEXP(")") -> MARK(End)};

Begin ANY+? {-> MARK(WordB)} tokenB;
```

but it marks all text from first Begin to first tokenA. How I can mark only WORDB ?

===========

I have a lot of text like this:

```
)))))WORD tokenA. A lot of text. 
(((((
)))))WORD tokenB. A lot of text. 
(((((
)))))WORD tokenC. A lot of text. 
(((((
)))))WORD tokenA. A lot of text. 
(((((
```

and etc, with a lot of different WORDs and a lot of different tokens. What I need? I need mark every WORD by its tag.

My code:

```
DECLARE Begin, End, tokenA, wordA;

ANY[5,5]{REGEXP(">") -> MARK(Begin)};
ANY[5,5]{REGEXP("<") -> MARK(End)};
W{REGEXP("tokena") -> MARK(tokenA)};
Begin ANY+? {-> MARK(wordA)} tokenA;
```

My bug:
http://postimg.org/image/9rudzlz7j/

==========================

Thank you, "and the ANY+? by a wildcard "#"" working like a charm for me!

Comment: Not sure I understand... What is WORD№ blocks? Could you explain again?

Comment: Can you provide an explicit input/output example? What should be the result?

Comment: Just guessing: add a start anchor "@" to tokenB: "Begin ANY+?{-> MARJ(WordB)} @tokenB;"

Comment: The rules are rather inefficient. You should maybe replace the ANY with SPECIAL or by a simple regexp rule. And the ANY+? by a wildcard "#".

Comment: @PeterKluegl, thank you a lot!